# parse xml data into Vector3

Tags: c#, xml, parsing

I'm coding this in C#.
I have an xml file that contains different points.

The xml file contains three different parts. First part contains vertices, second contains normal, and last contains indices.

I wanted to know how can I parse the xml file and store those values. My problem that I have is converting it to a Vector3 type.

Here is what the file looks like:

```
93.74445056915283,-1.859979498507132,2.36335901389315,
93.74445056915283,-1.939160544096572,2.368864585972887,93.74445056915283,
-1.781553864479065,3.202673300504684,93.74445056915283,-1.781567934571608,
2.36155147915304,93.74445056915283,-0.9234275662899016,3.202673300504684,
93.74445056915283,-1.623975274812637,2.368862884104112,93.74445056915283,
-1.703156483525081,2.363355632934579,93.74445056915283,-1.544259938449322,
```

Comment: This really needs more info, what specifically are you trying to achieve?

Comment: do you think it xml ?

Comment: this file is not xml...

Comment: are these values are multiple of 3 ? can you make sure ?

Comment: i.e 1st three belongs to first vector next 3 to next and so on ..

Comment: Yes it's an xml file that just contains different points. sm.abdullah is right every 3 values is a vector and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example looks more like decimal number separated by comas.
Also I'm assuming that you are referring to Vector3 from [Unity](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-ctor.html)

This sample returns list of Vector3.

```
var inputString = "93.74445056915283,-1.859979498507132,2.36335901389315, 93.74445056915283,-1.939160544096572,2.368864585972887, 93.74445056915283,-1.781553864479065,3.202673300504684, 93.74445056915283,-1.781567934571608,2.36155147915304, 93.74445056915283,-0.9234275662899016,3.202673300504684, 93.74445056915283,-1.623975274812637,2.368862884104112, 93.74445056915283,-1.703156483525081,2.363355632934579, 93.74445056915283,-1.544259938449322,2.378187850255953";
var coordinates = inputString.Split(',').Select(n => float.Parse(n, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat)).ToList();

var myVectors = new List<Vector3>();
for(var i=0;i<coordinates.Count;i+=3)
{
    var myVector = new Vector3(coordinates[i], coordinates[i+1], coordinates[i+2]);
    myVectors.Add(myVector);
}
```

I'm writing this code just from my head, so probably is not compilable.
Also mind that I'm assuming that all number are parsable to float (there are no special character and your locales' decimal point is a dot `.`). Also I'm assuming correct number of input numbers. As Vector3 requires 3 number in constructor, there have to be count divisible by three.

Comment: Fix the "new List<Vector3)() to <Vector3>

Comment: I'm actually using XNA framework. I will give your solution a try as well. Thanks!

Comment: You don't increment your i in the loop enough. It should be i += 3 not i++.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet of what I'm trying to achieve.

```
  using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("generator_0000001.xml"))
  {
     List<Vector3> verticesList = new List<Vector3>();
     while (reader.Read())
     {
         if (reader.IsStartElement())
         {
            switch (reader.Name)
            {
              case "Real64List":
              if (reader.Read())
              {
                float vertices = Convert.ToInt64(reader.Value.Trim());
                Vector3 oVert = new Vector3(vertices);
                verticesList.Add(oVert);
              }
              break;
            }
         }
      }
```

The file I'm trying to parse looks like this:
93.74445056915283,-1.859979498507132,2.36335901389315,
93.74445056915283,-1.939160544096572,2.368864585972887,
93.74445056915283,-1.781553864479065,3.202673300504684,
93.74445056915283,-1.781567934571608,2.36155147915304,
93.74445056915283,-0.9234275662899016,3.202673300504684,
93.74445056915283,-1.623975274812637,2.368862884104112,
93.74445056915283,-1.703156483525081,2.363355632934579,
93.74445056915283,-1.544259938449322,2.378187850255953.....

Comment: Could you include also snippet of the actual xml ?

Comment: This file is definitely not an xml. Anyway, could you take a look at my other answer ? I've included correct sample, which parses your input and returns List of Vector3.

Comment: @HoppusHoppard I did try your solution and was able to get it working, thanks.